# Memory issue when trying to assign pointer to new value

Tags: c

I'm having memory issues when trying to assign a new value to a pointer that was previously assigned a NULL value. I'm not too sure how to approach fixing the issue.

Here is my code. It is a linked list.

```
typedef struct Node {
    void* value;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

LinkedList* createLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList* linkedList;

    /* Assign memory to LinkedList */
    linkedList = (LinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    /* Assign default LinkedList Attributes */
    linkedList->head = NULL;
    linkedList->tail = NULL;
    linkedList->size = 0;

    return linkedList;
}

void insertFirst(LinkedList* linkedList, void* value)
{
    Node* newNode;
    Node* prevHead;

    newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    prevHead = linkedList->head;

    newNode->next = prevHead;
    newNode->prev = NULL;

    linkedList->head = newNode;

    linkedList->head = newNode;
    linkedList->size += 1;

}
```

The main function looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    linkedList = createLinkedList();
    insertFirst(linkedList, &testValue);
    insertLast(linkedList, &testValue);
    removeLast(linkedList);
    deleteList(linkedList);
}
```

I know that when I remove `linkedList->head = newNode`, from `insertFirst`, the program runs without any issue but obviously I lose the ability to access the new head value. Besides `insertLast`, All other functions run correctly when the above is removed.

When running with Valgrind, I get:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
```

which to my knowledge means that I am trying to access a value outside of the stack(?) but I have allocated memory for the new node and then pointing the `linkedList->tail` to the location of the new node.

As I said before, I am unsure about how to approach this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you use the functions? Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: By the way, in your `insertFirst` function, think about what happens with the lists tail pointer when adding the very first node.

Comment: Adding some more info now

Comment: Sidenote: don't use unnecessary casts. Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general.

Comment: Also worth noting: your `insertFirst` function doesn't actually assign to newNode->value.

Comment: You appear to be trying to implement a doubly-linked list, bu you don't assign the `prev`-pointer of `prevHead`. You also don't check whether the previous head was `NULL`.

Comment: You need to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means the code is trying to access (either read or write) memory location 0x10 (16).  This is certainly an access based on a NULL pointer.

That could happen if `malloc()` fails.  It can also occur if you use the prev or next field values before assigning them to a successful `malloc` result.

Comment: I will `malloc()` the value in the `createLinkedList()` and test it.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie:  Thank you!